# Does Mac or iOS development require plists to have the DOCTYPE header tag?

Tags: ios, xml, macos, plist, doctype

I am working on a tool to work with the plist files used in Mac and iOS development. By default these files have a `DOCTYPE` header, but that header is causing some strange issues for my tool. I tried removing it, and everything seems to work, but I am curious if I am missing something.

This is the header:

```
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
               "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

It is usually on the 2nd line, right after the XML header.

**My question is** if there is any circumstance, standard tool, check or process in the Mac or iOS development and execution experience that requires this line to be in the plist files? Like will it fail validation in the App store? Or was it only required for iOS 4, or some other issue? Removing this line is the easiest solution, but if it is necessary then I can find another way to make it work.